# Apple HomeKit Accessory Type

Tags: iso, homekit, ios-homekit

I am just understanding Apple HomeKit for building an demo app.
I see there are few predefined accessory types are given by Apple.
Like Switch, Fan and Thermostats etc.

What if I want to have some new type of accessory, which is not listed by Apple?  How do I create this new accessory (I know that this new accessory need to be manufactured by a Hardware manufacturer, and for that it needs to be registered as apple device manufacturer)?

Does apple allow to create new accessory type?

Answer (score 1):

You almost answered the question yourself. In order for a hardware to be classified as an 'HMAccessory', the hardware needs to be 'HomeKit' certified (see [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

The hardware manufacturing vendor will complete the MFi licensing procedure - in the process defining the accessory type.

So you don't need to worry about dealing with an undefined accessory type while programming a HMAccessory. By virtue of being an HMAccessory, that should be resolved for you.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. I'm running a node.js server to act as a HomeKit bridge. This bridge can define accessories and their characteristics without being in the MFi program. I just wrote a custom plugin to expose a "switch" to HomeKit to turn my TV on and off. I am still toying around to see if I can expand on the predefined types apple made.

Comment: Well, yes, that's a hack and you are simulating an HMAccessory, but not pertinent to the question being asked. My interpretation (I could be wrong) is that s/he meant an actual manufactured hardware HMAccessory fitting an accessory 'type' outside the Apple defined realm).

Also note that you created a soft 'switch' (which is a defined HMAccessory type), albeit you could probably create a type 'bed' that inflates/deflates. Anyway, good that you mentioned this.